# How to calculate the average while containg np.nan using np.average? (While using groupby)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df['C']=[5,2,np.nan,4,np.nan]
df['index']=df.index
```

The DataFrame:

```
  A  B   C   index
0 0  1   5     0
1 2  3   2     1
2 4  5   NaN   2
3 6  7   4     3
4 8  9   NaN   4
```

I want to use groupby funciton to calculate the average of "A""B""C" for every index.

```
df1 = df.groupby('index')
average = df1.apply(lambda df,x,y :np.average(df.iloc[:,x:y]),0,3)
```

The average:

```
index
0     2.00
1     2.33
2     NaN
3     5.67
4     NaN
dtype:float64
```

what I want to do is that :

1. when A B C are digits,the average = (A+B+C)/3
2. when one of ABC is np.nan, the average = sum/2

Comment: I don't know pandas, but can't you use `np.nanmean`?

Comment: @Paul Panzer OMG.np.nanmean solves the problem.

Comment: @jezrael what do you mean the unique index? the 'index' I used the here is just for groupby function

Comment: @DingruiZhang Happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom function:

You can use [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) - `NaN` are omited:

```
#groupby by index
df1 = df.groupby(level=0)
#groupby by column index
#df1 = df.groupby('index')

#filter columns for apply first, item() is for return scalar
average = df1['A','B','C'].apply(lambda x: x.mean(axis=1).item())
print (average)
0    2.000000
1    2.333333
2    4.500000
3    5.666667
4    8.500000
dtype: float64
```

Or with idea from [Paul Panzer comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312089/how-to-caculate-the-average-while-containg-np-nan-using-np-averagewhile-using#comment71778646_42312089):

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0)
average = df1['A','B','C'].apply(np.nanmean)
print (average)
0    2.000000
1    2.333333
2    4.500000
3    5.666667
4    8.500000
dtype: float64
```

Also `groupby` is not necessary, only select desired columns and use [`DataFrame.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df['new'] = df[['A','B','C']].mean(axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B    C  index       new
0  0  1  5.0      0  2.000000
1  2  3  2.0      1  2.333333
2  4  5  NaN      2  4.500000
3  6  7  4.0      3  5.666667
4  8  9  NaN      4  8.500000
```

---

```
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  0  1  5.0
1  2  3  2.0
2  4  5  NaN
3  6  7  4.0
4  8  9  NaN

#if need mean of all columns
df['new'] = df.mean(axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B    C       new
0  0  1  5.0  2.000000
1  2  3  2.0  2.333333
2  4  5  NaN  4.500000
3  6  7  4.0  5.666667
4  8  9  NaN  8.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use numpy instead of `pandas.mean()`?

```
df
Out[207]: 
   A  B    C
0  0  1  5.0
1  2  3  2.0
2  4  5  NaN
3  6  7  4.0
4  8  9  NaN

In [210]: df.mean(axis=1)
Out[210]: 
0    2.000000
1    2.333333
2    4.500000
3    5.666667
4    8.500000
dtype: float64
```

It does just what you need, and also works on `groupby` objects.

Comment: I want the average for each row not the columns

Comment: Set axis to 1 then it will do the rows.